# Kendo UI Chart as Wide as it Needs to be

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working with a vertical bar chart.  Each vertical bar represents a day.  The user can select a date range and thus there are X amount of columns (vertical bars) in the chart.  This is fine for perhaps about 50 days.  When you start having more days than that the labels for the dates (also vertical) start to overlap each other.  I know I can perhaps set the small and large tick amount to be a great value based on the date range and thus show fewer dates, but that is not what I am looking for.  I know that I can set the width of the chart area to anything I want, but the date range the user picks could be different.

So, I was wondering if there is a set with width of each vertical bar (day) and if I can set it to a value?  Then I would have a containing div that has a horizontal scroll bar.  Thus, for 30 days it may fit without scrolling but 50 and 60 and 150 will scroll.  No matter how many days are in the range, the column (day) width is consistent.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just use the pan and zoom capability of the chart:  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/pan-and-zoom

Comment: @ezanker you make a great point.  Oddly though as I add `zoomable: true` it does not do anything.  Even copied code from the demo page and that does not work.  Need to see what is breaking it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It works now.  I believe a trailing comma was crashing it.